Download TV ver apps from an android mobile with Play or whatsoever
I want to install android apps on TVs (AndroidTV) and for different reasons I prefer not using the play app on TV but from a  mobile. And extract the APK file and then send to the TV and install it.
BTW, most APKs from the android mobile app are displayed on portrait mode on a TV; besides other potential differences.

I don't have Android TV, so I can't test this, but APKMirror has a search filter for Android TV, if that's acceptable.

Easiest way would be using Aurora Store app directly on Android TV. If that doesn't work you can try to use Aurora Store on a phone using one of the provided fake hardware profiles (there are several TVs running Android in Aurora available). However I don't know what happens if Aurora Store tries to install the downloaded TV app on the phone.
